# Regex: match strings in separated lines

Tags: regex

community, how can I match the `name` and `executor` lines using regex under the section called [[runners]]

I was playing with things such as:

`(?=.*?(name.*))(?=.*?(executor.*))`

`(?<=\[runners\])[\s\S](\s*name.*)`

`/(?<=\[\[runners\]\])[\s\S](?=.*?(name.*))(?<=[\s\S])(?=.*?(executor.*))/g`

File example:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "admin"
  url = "url"
  token = "token"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]

[[runners]]
  name = "admin2"
  url = "url"
  token = "token"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
```

Expected result:

```
[[runners]]  
name = "admin"
executor = "shell"
[[runners]]
name = "admin2"
executor = "docker"
```

update:
based on @PoulBak comment the final solution for me is

`grep -E '\[\[runners\]\]|name = "[^"]+"|executor = "[^"]+"' /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`

Comment: What lang/tool? Is there always `[runners` after? (first inside square brackets after it)

Comment: @bobblebubble it is config.toml file for gitlab-runner. Yep, there is always [runners.smth] sections, but they can be empty and not always after 'executor' field

Comment: Try this: `/\[\[runners\]\]|name = "[^"]+"|executor = "[^"]+"/g`.

Comment: @PoulBak the solution you provided is much better than mine :)

Comment: @PoulBak that perfectly works! but not with Linux grep tool, it matches only names somehow. Anyways, thanks a lot!

Comment: it will look like this: `grep -E '\[\[runners\]\]|name = "[^"]+"|executor = "[^"]+"' /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`

Comment: You're dealing with structured data (TOML), and working with structured data with grep is usually painful and error-prone. Far better to just write a quick program that reads the data and parses it with a TOML parser. Surely whatever language you're using has existing code that will parse TOML for you.

Comment: I don't know Linux grep, but should't you double escape. like `\\[`?

Answer (score 1):

I made a demo using javascript as the regex performer.

My strategy was splitting the input string using double newline as separator with this statement:

`data.split(/\n\n/img);`

And then for each runner element returned above, use two different regex to fetch the properties name and executor.

The output will contain the string `[[runners]]` for any runner found in the input, but the properties name or executor will be listed only if existing in the input for the corresponding runner.

For this task a proper parser would be more appropriate because you could just have a cursor moving to the next line and keeping state of what's going on. Anyway I did my best to contain performance drawing for this task while using regex anywhere possible.

```js
const data = `
[[runners]]
  name = "admin"
  url = "url"
  token = "token"
  executor = "shell"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]

[[runners]]
  name = "admin2"
  url = "url"
  token = "token"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]

[[runners]]  
  url = "runnerWithNoName"
  token = "token"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]  
`;

let output = '';

const runners = data.split(/\n\n/img);
for(let runner of runners){  
  const name = /\s*name = "([^"]*)"/.exec(runner);
  const executor = /\s*executor = "([^"]*)"/.exec(runner);  

  output += "[[runners]]\n";
  if(name !== null) output += name[0].trim() + "\n";
  if(executor !== null) output += executor[0].trim() + "\n";  
}

console.log(output);
```